# Sonata 2 display 2 fields in the same column

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I display the list form of Sonata. I have 2 fields : firstname, lastname. I want to display 2 fields in the same column.

Currently, I'm doing

```
$listMapper->add('firstname', 'text', array('label' => 'First Name'))
           ->add('lastname', 'text', array('label' => 'Last Name'));
```

How can I combine 2 fields in one without to change the Entity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how i do it:

Say `firstname` and `lastname` are properties of User. In your entity class User, just add:

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getFullname()
{
    return sprintf("%s %s", $this->getFirstname(), $this->getLastname());
}
```

Then in your admin class:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
  $listMapper
  ...
     ->add('fullname', null, array('label' => 'Full Name'))
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works.This mean when I want to change the display of list, I neet to make the changes of the entity

Comment: Yes, sort of. You just need to add a public method to get the fullname, no need to change the orm though. Also consider accepting the answer if you estimate it's the right one.

Comment: When I display a column in the list, how can I add the with of this  $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('login', 'text', array('label' => 'Username', 'class' => 'the width'))

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use a [data transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html).

Or (and this doesn't seem like a good idea to me at all)you could do something like:

1. Add a non mapped field, call it fullName.
2. Add a PRE_SUBMIT form event listener which will populate fullName with firstName + LastName
3. Add a POST_SUBMIT form event listener which will then parse fullName back into lastName and firstName
4. Persist entity.