# How to combine firstName and lastName, then show it with Full name column in Sonata admin

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-4.2

I'm trying to show Full name column with firstName and lastName from entity. How can I do?

Here is my Entity and Admin.php:

```
class test{

private firstName;

//another properties

private lastName;

}
```

Admin

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper){
$listMapper
  ->add('id',null)
  ->add('Full name'); //I want to show the column like this (Full name = firstName + lastName)
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27223536/8237207. It's the same question as yours with an answer!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sonata 2 display 2 fields in the same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27220524/sonata-2-display-2-fields-in-the-same-column)

Answer (score 0):

try to use this inside your user Entity:

```
    /**
 * Get the full username if first and last name are set,
 * the username otherwise
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFullUsername(): string
{
    if ($this->firstname && $this->lastname) {
        return $this->firstname . ' ' . $this->lastname;
    }

    return $this->username;
}
```